# ¿Cuál es la mejor estrategia para crear una página por cada producto en mi web?

Tags: php

Si tengo muchos productos y cada uno tiene sus especificaciones , cada uno debería tener una página distinta , pero cual es la mejor manera de crear este contenido? , existen formas de crearlos dinámicamente y no tener que estar haciendo un archivo .php para cada una ?

PD : Solo busco entender la lógica para este desarrollo , pero por si acaso mi proyecto lo estoy haciendo con PHP (Codeigniter) y una base de datos MySQL

Comment: No conozco coseigniter, pero si es un framework lo que tendrías es un controlador de detalle de producto, que buscaría en la bbdd dicho producto y lo enviaría a una plantilla detalle. Esa plantilla, utilizando un motor de plantillas tipo twig, smart... Podría dibujar te la plantilla según los datos del producto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes varias opciones, ya vi que solucionaste el tema de las tablas anteriormente. La opción que se me ocurre a primera mano:

En la tabla general de productos agregas una columna con el nombre de la tabla que se debe consultar para conseguir las propiedades específicas de ese producto.
El diseño de tabla principal queda: `id, name, price, type`

Luego tienes que hacer una tabla para cada tipo de productos.
Por ej una tabla para cámaras quedaría así: `id, zoom, iso, model, brand`

Cuando queras consultar un artículo primero consultas la general.
 Te va ha devolver algo así:
`1, camara de 12mpx, 100, pr_camera`

Luego basándote en la respuesta, conusltas la tabla `pr_camera`.
La respuesta sería `1, 50x, 100-1600, sss-dxd, algunamarc`

**Este sería el código:**

```
<?php
//Conexion a la base de datos
$db = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "store");

//Conexion a la tabla de productos
//Primero se  busca el prducto en la tabla general de productos
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id=1");

$product = $query->fetch_array();

/*Esta variable sacada de la primera tabla 
define el tipo de producto, que coincide con 
el nombre de la segunda tabla donde se busca
las popiedades de este*/
$product_type = $product["type"];

//Consulta para la primera tabla
$product_espec_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `".$product_type."` WHERE id=".$product["id"].";");
$product_espec = $product_espec_query->fetch_array();

/*Esto sirve para traducir el nombre de 
la columna en una prpiedad legible y  bien escrita*/
    $property_names = array(
    "name"=>"Nombre",
    "price"=>"Precio",
    "id"=>"Identificador",

    //Nombres de propiedades para camara
    "type"=>"Tipo",
    "zoom"=>"ZOOM",
    "iso"=>"ISO",
    "model"=>"Modelo",
    "brand"=>"Fabricante",

    //Nombres de propiedades para telefono
    "screen"=>"Pantala",
    "batery"=>"Bateria",
    "cpu"=>"CPU"
    );


 /*Ahora se imprimen los valores de la priemra tabla
 $Clave es el nombre de la columna, que es convertido a
 un valor mas legible*/
foreach($product as $clave => $valor){
    if(!is_int($clave)){        
    echo($property_names[$clave].": ".$valor."<br/>");        
    }
}

//Ahora los valores de la segunda
foreach($product_espec as $clave => $valor){
    if(!is_int($clave)){

    echo($property_names[$clave].": ".$valor."<br/>");
    }
}
?>
```

También podrías hacerlo todo en una tabla, pero esto te traería serios problemas de mantenimiento, si alguna vez tienes que cambiar las propiedades de algún producto sería incómodo.